# float:left in a div not working as expected

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I can't float my second `div`.

I used `70%` from my website for my posts and I wanted to use `30%` to display a little text or something.

So i created a `div` and from what I know, I have to use "float: left" in order to let that `div` to go to the right place, under the banner.

I will post some pictures to let you know what I want.

I want  that red div to go there :

[image: SS]

There is my [codePen](http://codepen.io/kingofshadow55/pen/gMwggd)

```
<body>
<!-- the header of the website -->
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://s32.postimg.org/npddlgddx/logo.png"></div>
    <div class="header-text">
<!-- uncomment this later
      <h1>The Witcher</h1>
      <h2>The Wild hunt</h2> -->
    </div>
    <div class="header-menu">
      <ul>
      <!-- header list -->
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- left content -->
  <div class="left-content">
    <div class="posts">
      <h1> Blood and wine DLC </h1>
      <!-- post images -->
      <img src="https://s31.postimg.org/yvl2ismcr/photo1.png" class="img1" />
      <h1 style="margin-top: 55px"> Expansion Pass </h1>
      <img src="https://s31.postimg.org/lg5ef4et7/photo2.jpg" class="img1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- right content -->
  <div class="right-content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Also, could you tell me if the code looks nice or something?

Comment: So what's the problem ?

Comment: `what's wrong` and `tell me if the code looks` both are offtopic here.

Comment: sorry if i did something wrong. My problem is that i have a little red div there on the bottom of the webpage and i want to move it in the place where i made a circle in that picture, and i can't do this. I made my "content" div 70% and i hoped that my red div will go in that 30% that i didn't use if i use float:left but it didn't work. So i just want to move that div there. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `float: left;` to your both divs (left and right divs).

You can see implemented code here: https://jsfiddle.net/723fgs4d/1/

Comment: thanks you very much, it worked. I forgot to add float: left to my left content :)) thanks you again.

Comment: So it worked. cool. Please do not forget to mark the answer as Correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Set position of **.left-content** to absolute

```
.left-content{
width: 70%;
border-right: 1px solid black;
height: 900px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Set width of **.right-content** to 30% ( *optional* ), margin-left: auto, and remove the float line.

```
.right-content{
width: 30%;
height:200px;
background-color: red;
margin-left: auto;
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply fix this using `flexbox` instead and  removing `float`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #CED6D9;
}
/* header */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: url("https://s31.postimg.org/8wabf75rf/header.jpg");
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header-text {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.header-text h2 {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.logo img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
.header-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
.header-menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.header-menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #8E8E8E;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
.header-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
/* content */

.main {
  display: flex
}
.left-content {
  width: 70%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  height: 900px;
}
.posts {
  width: 55%;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
.posts .img1 {
  height: 380px;
  width: 100%;
}
.posts h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.right-content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1
}
/* responsive */

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .left-content {
    width: 100%;
    border-right: none;
  }
  .posts {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header-menu ul li a {
    color: black;
    display: block;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .left-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
  }
  .posts .img1 {
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- the header of the website -->
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://s32.postimg.org/npddlgddx/logo.png">
  </div>

  <div class="header-text">
    <!-- uncomment this later
   <h1>The Witcher</h1>
   <h2>The Wild hunt</h2> -->
  </div>
  <div class="header-menu">
    <ul>
      <!-- header list -->
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <!-- left content -->
  <div class="left-content">
    <div class="posts">
      <h1> Blood and wine DLC </h1>
      <!-- post images -->
      <img src="https://s31.postimg.org/yvl2ismcr/photo1.png" class="img1" />
      <h1 style="margin-top: 55px"> Expansion Pass </h1>
      <img src="https://s31.postimg.org/lg5ef4et7/photo2.jpg" class="img1" />
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- right content -->
  <div class="right-content"></div>
</div>
```